# Has Blade Templating Changed from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

**Issue:** Converting my Laravel 4 code to Laravel 5.  Nothing appears on the screen in between the  @section('container') & @stop.

**Notes:** I am using the Laravel Collective HTML Facades.  I have severely shortened the master.blade.php file for brevity.

**Request:** Please assist in figuring out why nothing is showing up in the browser and let me know in detail what I am doing wrong with examples, if possible.

**Error & Debug:** There is none.  The page is just blank.

**Attempts:** If I add anything outside the @section('container') & @stop then it shows up on the screen.

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
},
```

**app.php**

```
Providers Array
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

Alias Array
        'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

**master.blade.php**

```
  <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        @yield('container')
    </body>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
 @section('container')
  <!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<div style="margin: 10px 0 0 20px;border: 0px black dashed;width: 410px;float:left;">
        {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ContractController@store')) !!}
        {!! Form::token() !!}
<dl style="list-style-type:none;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>General Information</legend>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('contractterm','Contract Term', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('contractterm_id', $contracttermlist) !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('businesstype','Business Type', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('businesstype_id', $businesstypelist) !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('contract_date','Contract Starting Date', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('contract_date', date('m/d/Y'), array(
                    'size'=>'16',
                    'id' =>'datepicker'))
                !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('service_credit','Previous Service', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                <div style="float:right;width:140px;height:29px;"><span>Yes</span><span style="float:right;width:20px;padding-top:4px;padding-right:90px;">{!! Form::checkbox('prevcredit', 'credityes', false, array('class' => 'creditcheckbox','id' => 'prevcredit')); !!}</span></div>
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('credit_amount','Credit Amount', array('class' => 'label','id' => 'credit_amount')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('credit_amount','0.00',array('id' => 'credit_amount2')) !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('addtpcs','Additional PCs', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::select('addtpcs', $addtpcs) !!}
            </dd>
            <div id="inputs" style="margin:0;">
            </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('firstname','First Name', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('firstname') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('lastname','Last Name', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('lastname') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('hstraddr','Home Address', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('hstraddr') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('hcity','Home City', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('hcity') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('hstate','Home State', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('hstate', 'Florida') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('hzip','Home Zip Code', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('hzip') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('hphone','Home Phone', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('hphone') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('mobile','Mobile Phone', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('mobile') !!}
            </dd>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Business Information</legend>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('company','Company Name', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('company') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('bstraddr','Business Address', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('bstraddr') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('bcity','Business City', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('bcity') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('bstate','Business State', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('bstate', 'Florida') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('bzip','Business Zip', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('bzip') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
                {!! Form::label('bphone','Business Phone', array('class' => 'label')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('bphone') !!}
            </dd>
            <dd>
            <div class="submitbutton">
                    {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
            </div>
            </dd>
    </fieldset>
</dl>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
@stop
```

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Library\additionalPCs;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;
use App\Models\businesstype;
use App\Models\contractterm;


class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    Protected $layout = 'master';
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        /** Wayne - 03-02-2014 - Moved for loop to a method within its own class. */
        $numberofpcs = new additionalPCs();
        $addtpcs=$numberofpcs->display();
        //$this->layout->content = View::make('index')->with('addtpcs', $addtpcs)->with('businesstypelist', businesstype::dropdown())->with('contracttermlist',ContractTerm::dropdown());
        return view('index')->with('addtpcs', $addtpcs)->with('businesstypelist', businesstype::dropdown())->with('contracttermlist',ContractTerm::dropdown());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index.blade file you appear to be missing the extends tag that should appear at the very top, followed by your @section code

```
@extends('master')
@section('container')
   your section code here
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you Lucha.  This resolved the issue.  To whomever is reading this, look at Jeff's answer.  As of Laravel 5.1 the stop was replaced with endsection.  Update your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It's now `@section('container')` and then `@endsection` instead of `@stop` as of Laravel 5.1.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have updated that stop to endsection and will update the rest of the blade templates. This, unfortunately, did not resolve the issue.  Lucha's answer resolved the issue with or without the endsection or stop.